# Python: Replace string under a certain line

Tags: python, str-replace

sorry for writing, generally I try to avoid useless questions but I have been looking around for days without finding an answer to my problem.

Basically I have this piece of code inside a .txt file:

```
<item name="Find_this_keyword">
ente<value type="vector">[-0.1 0.2 0.3 1.4]
</item>
```

this line is inside a thousand lines similar to this that are differing only for that keyword. So basically I want python to change the line UNDER the line with that keyword.
I need to change the 4 numbers inside the vector with other 4 numbers.

Do you have any clue?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Demonstrate please what you have tried? A small code that shows essentials.

Comment: What you have is very close to a XML file (which is a filetype specifcally designed for storing data liked this). If you can start the file with `<xml>`, end it with `</xml>`, delete the "ente" bit and put `</value>` after every vector, then you can make it quite easy to parse in Python using the [ElementTree library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) which is part of the default python installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex to find the pattern and replace the value:

```
import re

pattern = '\[.+\]'
replace = '[num1, num2, num3, num4]'

file = open('code.txt', 'w')
    for line in file:
    if 'ente<value type="vector">' in line:
        re.sub(pattern, replace, line)
```

Just replace `num1`, `num2`, `num3`, `num4` with your new values.

Let them in string format if you won't use them for any maths.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

code.txt <- file with code

```
new_vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]
f1 = open('code.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('code_out.txt', 'a+')
for line in f1:
    newline = line
    if 'ente<value type="vector">' in line:  # check line by line and look if the prefix matches
         newline = 'ente<value type="vector">' + f'[{new_vals[0] {new_vals[1]} {new_vals[2]} {new_vals[3]}]'
    # replace the new line
    f2.write(newline)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```